# jQuery parallax moving background with text

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I am trying to replicate some functionality i quite like for a small project.

Here is the project: https://en.playkot.com/

I have manged to make the background move on mouse movement with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var movementStrength = 25;
    var height = movementStrength / $(window).height();
    var width = movementStrength / $(window).width();
    $("#top-image").mousemove(function(e){
        var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
        var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
        var newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 25;
        var newvalueY = height * pageY * -1 - 50;
        $('#top-image').css("background-position", newvalueX+"px     "+newvalueY+"px");

    });
});
```

I would also like the text to move on mouse movement.

I was just wandering if there are any libraries i can use, to get the same effect as the example above?

My project can be viewed here: http://super-code.co.uk/test.php

Answer (score 0):

which text you are refering to..??I am not able to see any text....the text "PLAYKOT" is embedded in IMG..
You can try with this dinosaur moving code....

```
$('#dinosaur').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).find('img').css('left', '50px');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).find('img').css('left', '0px');
});
```

Comment: Yes "PLAYKOT" which is'nt embedded. It is text if you inspect the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#top-image").mousemove(function(e){
      var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
      var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
      var newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 25;
      var newvalueY = height * pageY * -1 - 50;
      $('#top-image').css("background-position", newvalueX+"px     "+newvalueY+"px");

      $(".pa" ).css("transform","translate("+ newvalueX+"px ," +newvalueY+"px)");

    });
```

Add last line will Work...